# xts package: format date as seconds only

Tags: r, xts

I have a matrix `X` where each column represents a time series. Each row doesn't represent a year, month or day, but rather a second. I'd like to use the xts package but have the dates just be 1,2,3,..., nrow(X), i.e. from 1 to the last second in the series, since each row is one second ahead of the previous. Is this possible? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: xts objects must be indexed by a datetime class.  A second is not a datetime. Either add arbitrary values for year, month, day, hour, minute; or just use zoo, which doesn't have the datetime index requirement.

Comment: Thanks! I guess zoo is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** This can be done with zoo:

```
library(zoo)
X <- matrix(1:6, 3) + 100 # test data
zoo(X)
```

giving the following (the 1, 2, 3 column is the times):

```
1 101 104
2 102 105
3 103 106
```

**2)** `xts` does not support raw numbers as times (see `?xts`) but you could use the fact that the `"POSIXct"` class is expressed in seconds internally.  It will show up as POSIXct date times but internally it will be the seconds you asked for:

```
library(xts)
x <- xts(X, as.POSIXct(1:nrow(X), origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

giving:

```
> x
                    [,1] [,2]
1969-12-31 19:00:01  101  104
1969-12-31 19:00:02  102  105
1969-12-31 19:00:03  103  106

> unclass(time(x))
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""
attr(,"tclass")
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```